# Making a LinkedList: Adding in order

Tags: c#-4.0, recursion

I need to create a `LinkedList`. I have a class called `Node` with an `int` attribute and a `Node` attribute. I need to be able to add items to the LinkedList in descending order.

I have code that can add items to the beginning of the list if the given number is higher than the highest in the list. Same thing with the lowest number. The problem shows up when trying to add a `Node` in the middle of the list. I need to use recursion. I have already used it to find the highest and lowest number, but I can't get to code for that last case (adding in the middle).

Can you give me a hint? Maybe tell me which is the base case?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
Node root = null;

    public void Add(int data)
    {
        Node m = new Node();
        m.data = data;

        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node();
            root.data = data;
            root.Next = null;
        }

        else if (root.Next == null)
        {                    
            if (m.data > root.data)
            {
                Node tempRoot = root;
                root = m;
                m.Next = tempRoot;
                tempRoot.Next = null;
            }

            else
            {
                root.Next = m;
                m.Next = null;
            }
        }

        else if (m.data > root.data)
        {
            m.Next = root;
            root = m;
        }

        else
        {
            Node temp = root;
            Node x = Insert(temp, m);

            for (; temp != x; temp = temp.Next) ;
            m.Next = temp.Next;
            temp.Next = m;
        }
    }

    public Node Insert(Node n, Node insertMe)
    {
        if (n.Next == null)
        {
            return n;
        }

        else
        {
            if (insertMe.data >= Insert(n.Next, insertMe).data)
            {
                return n;
            }

            else
            {
                return Insert(n.Next, insertMe);
            }
        }
    }
```